# Aura:if - check with a regular expression

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, aura-if

Is it possible to write aura:if conditions with regular expressions.
Ia m trying remove records if the a certain field in that record is not a number.

```
<aura:if isTrue="{! !add.sumchans__suiteNumber__c == ^[0-9]*\d$}">
```

Right now I am handling this in js controller.

Pls advise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, doing this in the controller is the right way. There isn't a way to do regular expressions inside Lightning Expressions anyways, but even if you could, you'd still get better performance doing this in the controller/helper itself.